# How to get the column name of the cell which returned by result::fetch_row if I use foreach on it?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a simple php code to print the result of a mysqli query no matter what query it is and how many columns and rows in there. My simplified php code is:

```
$result = $mysqli->query ($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
   if ($row["status"] == "0") continue;
   foreach ($row as $cell) {
       echo $cell;
   }
   echo "\n";
}
```

Now I want to omit some column (ex: column named "status") to be printed, but I have to include the column "status" in the query because I need to check this "status" value to determine whether if the entire row will be printed or not (the check is a little more complicated than that and it's impractical to do it on the query itself). But if the row is printed, I don't want the column "status" is printed along in the table. But I have no means to know whether the $cell I get inside foreach is named "status" or not, and I have several other columns that have similar value like "status" so I can't check based on value either. How can I do this? I've read on php mysqli::fetch_row() manual but it doesn't seem that each of the $cell is an object that can be applied method to ask what's its column name. Thanks.

Comment: Use `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_row()`; and then `foreach ($row as $columnName => $cell)`

Comment: @MarkBaker oh, right, it IS a dictionary! Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaker you should put your comment as answer, so I can mark it as accepted. :) thanks for the fetch_assoc tip too!

Answer (score 0):

So only select the rows with status !=0

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM user WHERE status!=0;
```

Update:

```
unset($row["status"]);
var_dump($row);
```

Comment: I can't, because the conditional comparison for status is a complicated, and some of the evaluation is also based on some external values, which will make the query will be very complicated if I put it all in the query. Not to mention that the query itself is already complicated the way it is now lol. Thanks anyway.